# collectionRferece.doc() required its first argument to be of not empty string but was undefined?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

my title question maybe duplicated but, I think its different :D..

I want to update array in firestore ... first time it work ,the second time will
give me this

**warning: virtualizedlist: missing keys for items**

and give me this error: **collectionRferece.doc() required its first argument to be of not empty string but was undefined**

I explained my code step by step.

**Home.js**

I receive data from firestore and i send it as a prop to projectList

```
    render(){
        const {projects,auth}=this.props;
        return(

                <ProjectList projects={projects} />
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
    return{
        projects:state.firestore.ordered.projects,
    }
}
export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps),firestoreConnect([{collection:'projects',orderBy:['createdAt','desc']}])) (Feed);
```

**ProjectList.js**

there is just a flat list and sending data as a prop to projectsummery

```
const ProjectList =({projects})=> {
        return(

            <FlatList
                data={projects} 
                refreshing={true}
                renderItem={(project)=>{
                    return(
                        <ProjectSummery project={project}  key={project.item.id}
                         keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.item.id}
                        />
                    )
            } }
            /> 
        )
        }
```

**ProjectSummery.Js**

there is some design and button, when i press the button i send project.item.id which is a (doc id) in firestore to project actions.js there is likePosts function which is update the array in firestore

```
import {likePosts} from '../Store/Actions/ProjectActions'

const  ProjectSummery =(props)=> {
      const {project,auth}=props

       console.log(project.item.id);

      return(
        <>
            <Container style={{flex:0,height:180}} >
        <Content >
          <Card>
            <CardItem>
              <Left>
                <Button transparent onPress={()=>props.likePosts(project.item.id)}>
                  <Text>{project.item.likes.length} Likes</Text>
                </Button>
              </Left>

          </Card>
          </Content>
      </Container>

      </>
        )
    }

const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
    return{
        likePosts:(postId)=>dispatch(likePosts(postId))
    }
}

export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(ProjectSummery);
```

**Actions.js**

here i have likePosts fuction which update the array in firestore,
the fist time it works but the second time (project.item.id) postId will be undefined and i have no idea what's going on :D

```
export const likePosts =(postId)=>{

    return (dispatch,getState,{getFirebase,getFirestore})=>{
        const profile=getState().firebase.profile
        const authId=getState().firebase.auth.uid
        const firestore=getFirestore()

            console.log(postId);

            firestore.collection('projects').doc(postId).update({

            likes:firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
            likedAt:new Date(),
            likedBy: authId,
            name: profile.firstName + profile.lastName

            })


        })  

        }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone ends up on this question facing a similar issue, there is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59290513/firestore-document-id-will-be-undefined-after-i-update-array/59306474#59306474) that appears to be different but the issue is caused by the same reason.

Check my answer there and the comments in under the question itself.

In addition to that, you can also check the Pagination section of [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-firebase-realtime-database#firebase-realtime-database-pagination#Title-module--title--1OAU8) for more guidance.

**Original Answer:**

What's happening is that when you click a like button the first time, it's working as expected so it gets the proper postId and then continues with the process you have defined. However, when you try the 2nd time it fails to fetch the postId as it's already liked.

The idea is that you'll need to either define an if statement and specify what should happen if it's already clicked and it get's clicked again (possibly storing the postId somewhere the first time and using it from there), or make an initial check that returns a specific message to the user if it's already clicked.

The issue has nothing to do with Firestore itself but with the button and the states of liked/unliked.

Here is one nice interactive example on *codepen.io* of a proper way of building like buttons using react. [React Like Button](https://codepen.io/jordanhope/pen/EyGkRv)

**HTML**

```
<div id="example"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-primary {
  background-color: #23aa4e;
  border-color: #177d37;
}

#example {
  margin: 3rem;
}

.customContainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**JS**

```
class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      liked: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  } 

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      liked: !this.state.liked
    });
  }

  render() {
    const text = this.state.liked ? 'liked' : 'haven\'t liked';
    const label = this.state.liked ? 'Unlike' : 'Like'
    return (
      <div className="customContainer">
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {label}</button>
        <p>
          you {text} this. Click to toggle.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <LikeButton />,
  document.getElementById('example')
)
```