# firestore document id will be undefined after I update array

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have this flatlist which receive data from firestore and send as props to projectsummery.js

```
const ProjectList =({projects})=> {
        return(
            <FlatList
                data={projects} 
                renderItem={(project,index)=>{
                    return(
                        <ProjectSummery project={project}  key={project.item.id}
                         //keyExtractor={(item, index) =>item.id}/>
                    )
            } }
            />  
        )
        }
```

Here I have a button which which sends document id which is something like this
{project.item.id} == **CSmet3tRjpjDcJ437M78**

**ProjectSummery.js**

```
    const  ProjectSummery =(props)=> {
          const {project,auth}=props      
          return(
            <>
            <View >
            <Text> {project.item.title} </Text>
            <Text>likes { project.item.likes.length}</Text>
            <Text>{project.item.id}</Text>//document id in in firestore
            <View>
              <Button title='like' onPress{()=>props.likesPosts(project.item.id)}/>
            </View>
            </View>
  const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
    return{
        likePosts:(postId)=>dispatch(likePosts(postId))
    }
}
```

When I try to update array in firebase the first time it work but the second time the document id will be undefined. I use React-Native. Thanks for help...

```
export  const likePosts =  (postId) => {
    
    return (dispatch,getState,{getFirebase,getFirestore})=>{
        const profile=getState().firebase.profile
        const authId=getState().firebase.auth.uid
        const firestore=getFirestore()
       
        firestore.collection('projects').doc(postId).update({
                                       //this postId will be be undefined in the 2nd time
             likes:firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                likedAt:new Date(),
                likedBy:authId,
                name: profile.firstName 
            })
          
        })
        }}
```

The fist update postId == **CSmet3tRjpjDcJ437M78** in the 2nd time postId will be **undefined**

Comment: I have tried to replicate what you are doing but no issues occur. It seems like whatever method is giving you the postId is the issue. Can you share the code where postId is declared ?

Comment: Thanks for  replay... I asked before but no one answer me , I explained my code  at here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272043/collectionrferece-doc-required-its-first-argument-to-be-of-not-empty-string-bu

Comment: I see that you have console.log(postId). Could you please edit the question above and add that part of code + the logs that you get in the first update and in the 2nd ? This will help me eliminate possibilities of what is going wrong. @Ahmed

Comment: @Waelmas I edited. could you read again thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that when you click a like button the first time, it's working as expected so it gets the proper postId and then continues with the process you have defined. However, when you try the 2nd time it fails to fetch the postId as it's already liked.

The idea is that you'll need to either define an if statement and specify what should happen if it's already clicked and it get's clicked again (possibly storing the postId somewhere the first time and using it from there), or make an initial check that returns a specific message to the user if it's already clicked.

The issue has nothing to do with Firestore itself but with the button and the states of liked/unliked.

Here is one nice interactive example on *codepen.io* of a proper way of building like buttons using react. [React Like Button](https://codepen.io/jordanhope/pen/EyGkRv)

**HTML**

```
<div id="example"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-primary {
  background-color: #23aa4e;
  border-color: #177d37;
}

#example {
  margin: 3rem;
}

.customContainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**JS**

```
class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      liked: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  } 

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      liked: !this.state.liked
    });
  }

  render() {
    const text = this.state.liked ? 'liked' : 'haven\'t liked';
    const label = this.state.liked ? 'Unlike' : 'Like'
    return (
      <div className="customContainer">
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {label}</button>
        <p>
          you {text} this. Click to toggle.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <LikeButton />,
  document.getElementById('example')
)
```